# How to display background image in servlet

Tags: image, servlets, resources, relative-path

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>ServletApplication</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>DemoServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>DemoServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.mayu.servlet.DemoServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>DemoServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/DemoServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>Login</display-name>
    <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.mayu.servlet.Login</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Login</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>RoomMaster</display-name>
    <servlet-name>RoomMaster</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.mayu.servlet.RoomMaster</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>RoomMaster</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/RoomMaster</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

above you see my Web-xml

this is output i need, but when integreted with servlet i get only login without image[image: and this is output without servlet]

```css
 .hr {
            background: url("../img/login.jpg");
        }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Reservation</title>
    <!-- Include CSS File Here -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/Site.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <!-- Include JS File Here -->
    <!--<script src="js/login.js"></script>-->
    <script src="js/jquery-1.9.0.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    
</head>
<body class="hr">
    <form id="myform" method="post" action="RoomType.html" name="myform">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-10 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-offset-2">
                <div class="jumbotron">
                    <form class="form-horizontal" style="margin-top:50px; margin-bottom:50px;">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="inputEmail3" class="col md-2 col-sm-2 col-md-offset-2 control-label" style="padding:0px;">User Id</label>
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                <input type="text" name="username" id="username" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-md-offset-2 control-label" style="padding:0px;">Password</label>
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" />

                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-3">
                                <!--<input type="button" value="Login" id="submit" onclick="myFunction()"/>-->
                                <input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Login">
                            </div>
                        </div>


                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            document.getElementById("myform").submit();
        }

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.combobox').combobox();
            //$('.combobox').combobox({newOptionsAllowed: false});
            $('form').submit(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                alert($('input[name="normal"]').val());
                alert($('input[name="horizontal"]').val());
                alert($('input[name="inline"]').val());
            });
        })

        //document.getElementById("TextBox1").value = Date()
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am doing a web base project working on `servlet`, in that I created `servlet page` and added my `css`,`js`,`img folder` to the `WebContent folder`. My problem is I set a `image` to the body background that image can't seen on browser. i added my login page code please see and help me to solve this.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is the URL to retrieve the page you have shown above? What is the URL to retrieve the 'login.jpg' image separately?

Comment: See till i have a login page with background image, html code work fine when run without servlet, but when that html code added in servlet then the background image not working all the other are working my validations,css are working only background image not working

Comment: Please share contents of your web.xml

Comment: No idea if related but you have nested forms. That's illegal

Comment: Do you see a resource not found error in browser's console?!

Answer (score 0):

Try making following change:

```
.hr {
        background-image: url("/img/login.jpg");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong way to get the image, the path of your file depends on the name of your war so the best way to do it would be by using , so if you have this structure:

```
Webapp
 |-- img
 |    `-- login.jpg
 `-- WEB-INF
      |-- 
      `--
```

Your images url would be: `'my_portlet_021_/img/login.jpg'` and to set this image as a background I suggest using jQuery in jsp this way:

```
var url='url(<%= request.getContextPath()%>/img/login.jpg)';
$('.hr').css("background-image", url);
```

here `<%= request.getContextPath()%>`  gets the name of your web app.